# How to send a notification at a random time?

Tags: node.js, express, push-notification, notifications, backend

I would like to find out how, using Node.js, Express, Typeorm I can send notifications at random times to users to add a post etc.

I would like to create something of the BeReal sort. Notifications should be sent according to the user's selected time zone at random times.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to send automated notifications, I'd recommend using
  [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). However, for your case, I'd propose to add a timeZone
  indicative information in the database to link the user with the
  timeZone(you can find it in HTTP Requests, update it after each
  login).
- For the actual sending of the notifications, I think you should use
  some third party service like Google Firebase for mobile
  notifications, and [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) for web applications.